# Slower training per epoch with increasing number of GPUs for a DNN model - Tensorflow / Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, tf.keras

So I have a Sequantial keras model with say, 3 Dense layers with 1024, 512 and 256 nodes between the input and output layers. I can create a MirroredStrategy using 1 - 2 and 4 GPUs. The model is defined as :

`with strategy.scope(): model = self.build_model(xtrain) opt = self.optimizer(learning_rate) model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)`

where

`strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(GPUS)`

The batch size is :
`32* strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`

Now, for each epoch, if the model takes ~ 50 seconds with one GPU; with 2 GPUs, it's taking about 1.30 mins, i.e., ~ 90 seconds and about the same time with 4 GPUs.

My training data is custom data for a specific problem I am working on and is fed to `model.fit` as numpy arrays.

Could someone explain why I am seeing something like this?

I was expecting to see a reduction in time for training each epoch instead of an increase!

Comment: there is an overhead in using distributed computing, probably your model is not big enough to "surpass" this fixed cost of distributed computing

Comment: I guessed that this might be the case. So I increased the number of layers - nodes etc to a very large number where one GPU took ~ 5 mins for one epoch. 4GPUs told me each epoch would take an hour. Although, I'm not sure if this is the best way of checking the overhead